# Kotlin: Trying to add the following function to a global shared file to be used in multiple activities but keep getting different errors

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add the following code to a common file to be shared between multiple activities but keep getting many errors:

```
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (currentFocus != null) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

this function is used to collapse the keyboard when I click away from a text EditText field.

> Errors: unresolved reference: currentFocus
>
> Errors: unresolved reference: getSystemService
>
> Errors: unresolved reference: dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: Where you are calling this function from?

Comment: This is an overridden function you cannot use this function outside an Activity.

Comment: @Black4Guy There is no way to use this is multiple activities without using the entire code in each?

Comment: Extend AppCompatActivity and put it in that. Have all your Activities extend from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function in your shared file for collapse the keyboard

```
 fun hideKeyboard(context: Context) {
                val inputManager =
                    context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                val v = (context as Activity).currentFocus ?: return
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
            }
```

In Activity override **dispatchTouchEvent()** function and call hideKeyboard() function like:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
if (currentFocus != null) {
hideKeyboard(this)
}
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Comment: This results in 2 unresolved reference errors:
- activity and windowToken

Comment: what are those ?

Comment: currentFocus is causing problem ?

Comment: No, 'Activity' and 'windowToken'

Comment: You need to import Activity class here that's it

Comment: What needs to be passed in as param in the activity where the fun in invoked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211579/discussion-between-black4guy-and-berheet).

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you so that it may help others too. Thanks

Comment: Why not make the function take an Activity argument rather than take a Context argument and casting it to Activity?

Comment: Because in that way we can use this function either from Activity, Fragment, Adapter. we use context in Adapter instead of Activity for getting the context.